# Чи треба писати Мати Тереза з великої літери?

Tags: власні-назви, велика-мала-літера

За правилами [Правопису](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/38/),

> 1. З великої літери пишуться індивідуальні імена людей, по батькові, прізвища, псевдоніми, конспіративні клички, прізвиська: Іва́н
>      Петро́вич Котляре́вський, Ле́ся Украї́нка (Лари́са Петрі́вна Ко́сач),
>      Ма́рко Вовчо́к (Марі́я Олекса́ндрівна Вілі́нська), Ю́рій Клен
>      (О́свальд Бу́ргардт), Дани́ло Га́лицький, Не́стор Літопи́сець,
>      Олекса́ндр Не́вський, Яросла́в Му́дрий; також: Кобза́р (про Тараса
>      Шевченка), Каменя́р (про Івана Франка) тощо.
>
> У складних прізвищах, псевдонімах та іменах, **які пишуться через дефіс**,
>   кожна складова частина починається великою літерою:
>   Кві́тка-Основ’я́ненко, Нечу́й-Леви́цький, Сергє́єв-Це́нський;
>   Жан-Жа́к, Зино́вій-Богда́н, Марі́я-Тере́за.

Якщо назву Мати Тереза вважати прізвиськом, то немов треба писати з великої літери, навіть незважаючи на відсутність дефісу. Та у Вікіпедії є [стаття](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), що починається зі слів "Свята мати Тереза", де слово *мати* - з малої літери. Яке правило діє у даному випадку?

Comment: Мати - це звернення до монахині, що має сан священника. До чоловіків звертаються "отче": http://ktds.org.ua/news/publish/yak-pryinyato-zvertatys-do-dukhovnykh-osib-etyketni-movlenevi-formuly/ Це приблизно як у військових звертаються за званням (лейтенант, капітан) або до посадовців - директор, президент і т.і.

Comment: @ Artemix, але ж у даному випадку звичайне звертання стало частиною імені власного, чи не так? Інакше воно би завжди писалося з малої літери.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[НАПИСАННЯ ВЕЛИКОЇ ЛІТЕРИ У РЕЛІГІЙНІЙ ЛЕКСИЦІ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/60/53405/388990.html)

> 11. З великої літери пишемо офіційні назви та повні титули найвищих церковних посад (голів патріярших, архиєпископських,
>       верховноархиєпископських, митрополичих Церков): Патріярх Київський і
>       всієї Руси-України, Папа Римський Павло VI, Вселенський Архиєрей,
>       Римський Архиєрей, Верховний Архиєпископ, Києво-Галицький Митрополит,
>       Глава самоуправної Церкви та ін.
>
> Примітка 1. У контекстах, які не передбачають наголошення офіційности
>   найвищих церковних посад, у наукових текстах, а також на позначення
>   родових понять, їх назви пишемо з малої літери:
>
> - папа Іван ХХIII скликав Вселенський Собор
> - Царгородський патріярх Фотій
> - обрання Київського патріярха
> - митрополит Московський Йов заявив
> - послання екзарха України
> - влада Римського архиєрея
> - Іларіона вибрали Київським митрополитом.

В Вікіпедії є стаття де ***"мати"***  пишемо з великої літери

> [Сестри Матері Терези](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9C%D1%96%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) рідше Орден Милосердя (лат. Congregatio
>   Sororum Missionarium Caritatis, абревіатура конгрегації — MC) —
>   католицька чернеча конгрегація (згромадження) офіційно визнана та
>   заснована у 1950 році Матір'ю Терезою.

Отже, "мати" як звернення до монахині пишемо з малої літери, але якщо потрібно підкреслити офіційність церковної посади, то пишемо з великої літери.

Тож правильним є написання обох варіантів.

Comment: але ж у вікі може бути просто помилка, її ж заповнюють не суто лінґвісти. я зібрався голосувати за відповідь, але оцей вікі-арґумент заважає. хоча, може, я прискіпуюсь...

Comment: @P.Vovk так, я з Вами згодна вікі не зовсім надійне джерело, але краще за форум.

Comment: голосую вгору з надією, що ви знайдете шлях покращити відповідь трохи, як буде час.

Comment: @P.Vovk обов'язково покращу, як знайду ще хоч одне надійне джерело